# Im having trouble validating a computers AD group membership in batch scripting, blank output

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to use a script to determine if a list of computers objects are a member of two specific AD groups (amongst other things) represented by GroupA and GroupB in the code, but its returning blank results in the spreadsheet (example below). I don't have any formal training with Powershell but I have been trying my butt off trying to learn it over the past year or so. I usually don't ask for help, but I really cant figure this one out to save my life and would be eternally grateful for any help.

This is the code that I am having trouble with:

```
$comp = Import-CSV .\PCList.csv
$Results = 
$comp | foreach {
<#
Pulls information from each computer in the list
#>
    if ($true) {

        $IPv4Address = Get-ADComputer -identity $_.computer -properties * | select-object IPv4Address
        $Enabled = Get-ADComputer -identity $_.computer -properties * | select-object Enabled
        $CanonicalName = Get-ADComputer -identity $_.computer -properties * | select-object CanonicalName
        $LastLogonDate = Get-ADComputer -identity $_.computer -properties * | select-object LastLogonDate
        $groupA = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership (Get-ADComputer $_.computer) | select-object MemberOf |where-object {$_.SamAccountName -ccontains "GroupA"}
        $groupB = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership (Get-ADComputer $_.computer) | select-object MemberOf |where-object {$_.SamAccountName -ccontains "GroupB"}
        }
<#
Converts data to a formal name for the Output file
#>
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'ComputerName'      = $_.computer
            'IPv4Address'       = $IPv4Address.IPv4Address
            'Enabled?'          = $Enabled.Enabled
            'OU'                = $CanonicalName.CanonicalName
            'Last Logon Date'   = $LastLogonDate.LastLogonDate
            'GroupA Membership?'= $groupA
            'GroupB Membership?'= $groupB
        }
        }
$Results | Export-Csv -Path .\Data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

When I run this code, I get blank results where the AD groups should be:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMMdl.png)

To add to my confusion, if I run these commands in a different script they run just fine and produce the intended results:

```
$comp = Import-CSV .\PCList.csv
$Results = 
$comp | foreach {
<#
Pulls information from each computer in the list
#>
    if ($true) {
        $cn = Get-ADComputer -identity $_.computer -properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DNSHostName
        $mo = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership (Get-ADComputer $_.computer) | select-object SamAccountName |where-object {$_.SamAccountName -ccontains "GroupA"}
        

<#
Converts data to a formal name for the Output file
#>
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'ComputerName'         = $cn 
            'MemberOf'             = $mo.SamAccountName
            
            
        }
    }
<#
Error handling for systems that cannnot be reached or where data cannot be pulled, enters N/A for vaules in the output file
#>
    else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'ComputerName'         = 'Unknown'
            'MemberOf'             = 'Unknown'

        } 
    }
  
}
$Results | Export-Csv -Path .\Data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm at a loss as to why this code works in one script but not the other. Please help me learn how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues.

First, there is no memberof property for objects returned by `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`

Next, if that property did exist, when you `Select-Object SomeProperty` that returns an object with just that property. Therefore you wouldn't be able to check the SamAccountName because it does not exist on the object passed along.

Also, you choose `-Properties *` when you really only need a few - this puts extra overhead on your domain controllers and slows the entire script down.

Finally, you make 6 identical calls to `Get-Adcomputer` and 2 to `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`

Here is one way to only make the calls required with the properties desired.

```
$props = 'IPv4Address','Enabled','CanonicalName','LastLogonDate'

$computerlist = Import-CSV .\PCList.csv

$Results = foreach($computer in $computerlist)
{
    Get-ADComputer $computer.computer -Properties $props | Foreach-Object {
        $grps = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_ |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ComputerName        = $computer.computer
            IPv4Address         = $_.IPv4Address
            'Enabled?'          = $_.Enabled
            'OU'                = $_.CanonicalName
            'Last Logon Date'   = $_.LastLogonDate
            'GroupA Membership?'= $grps -contains 'GroupA'
            'GroupB Membership?'= $grps -contains 'GroupB'
        }
    }
}

$Results | Export-Csv -Path .\Data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you Doug! I'm still very new to powershell and haven't made it out of the "crude" coding phase yet lol. I think I accidently left the memberof function in there when I was playing around with the code (it was a long day for me). Thank you for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it! I hope you have a great holiday! Thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped. Thank you, happy holidays.